# Python - get first and last observation per week, month, quarter, six months, year, etc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset (Pandas dataframe) that looks like this:

```
         Date      Open      High  ...       date  year  month
0  2002-05-23  1.156429  1.242857  ... 2002-05-23  2002      5
1  2002-05-24  1.214286  1.225000  ... 2002-05-24  2002      5
2  2002-05-28  1.213571  1.232143  ... 2002-05-28  2002      5
3  2002-05-29  1.164286  1.164286  ... 2002-05-29  2002      5
4  2002-05-30  1.107857  1.107857  ... 2002-05-30  2002      5
```

How can I get the first and last observation per week, month, quarter, 6 months, year etc? I would like to get the prices from the dataset and then calculate the return for each respective period.

EDIT:

Your code gives me the following output for df1:

```
Index        first    last
2002-05-26   1.15643  1.21429
2002-06-02   1.21357  1.07857
```

I would like to have:

```
First date       Last date     First value    Last value
2002-05-26       2005-06-01    1.15643        1.21429
2002-06-02       2002-06-09    1.21357        1.07857
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with aggregate `first` and `last`:

```
df1 = df.resample('W', on='Date')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])
df2 = df.resample('M', on='Date')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])
df3 = df.resample('Q', on='Date')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])
df4 = df.resample('6M', on='Date')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])
df5 = df.resample('Y', on='Date')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
         Date  Open
0  2002-05-23   1.1
1  2002-05-24   1.2
2  2002-05-28   1.3
3  2002-05-29   1.4
4  2002-05-30   1.5
5  2002-05-31   1.6
6  2002-06-01   1.7
7  2002-06-02   1.8
8  2002-06-03   1.9
9  2002-06-04   2.0

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df1 = df.resample('W', on='Date')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])
print (df1)
            first  last
Date                   
2002-05-26    1.1   1.2
2002-06-02    1.3   1.8
2002-06-09    1.9   2.0

df1 = df.set_index('Date').resample('W')['Open'].agg([('First date', lambda x: x.index[0]),
                                                      ('Last date', lambda x: x.index[-1]),
                                                      ('First value','first'),
                                                      ('Last value','last')])
print (df1)
           First date  Last date  First value  Last value
Date                                                     
2002-05-26 2002-05-23 2002-05-24          1.1         1.2
2002-06-02 2002-05-28 2002-06-02          1.3         1.8
2002-06-09 2002-06-03 2002-06-04          1.9         2.0
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I got the following error: `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: @adrCoder - Then use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` before and also parameter `on` in `resample`

Comment: I accepted your answer but what do you mean parameter "on" in resample? You already have this parameter in your code, right?

Comment: And can I somehow get the dates for the first and last observations per group too?

Comment: @adrCoder - yes, but if forget it, get same error. Because resample want use `Datetimeindex` if not use `on` parameter

Comment: How can I get the first and last dates per grouping? (e.g. first and last date per week, month, quarter, year etc)?

Comment: @adrCoder - then use `df1 = df.set_index('Date').groupby('group').resample('W')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])`

Comment: For this is necessary DatetimeIndex, so no parameter `on`

Comment: `df1 = df.set_index('Date').groupby('group').resample('W')['Open'].agg(['first','last'])` gives me an error `KeyError: 'group'`

Comment: @adrCoder - yes, it is group column, because need per grouping. But maybe I understand it wrong... Can you explain more what mean `grouping` ?

Comment: At the moment your code returns one date per row: in the index column. I would like to have both the first and the last dates for every week, every month, every quarter etc. Not only one date, both dates for every row.

Comment: @adrCoder - hmmmm, I think I understand. But because different frequency in resample need `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ...], axis=1, keys=('W','M','Q','6M','Y'))`. Get  `DatetimeIndex` by union of all `DatetimeIndex`es of each DataFrame (df1, df2...) and some missing values - reason is e.g. if exist some datetime in df1 and not in df2, df3, .., dfn tehn is value in output only for first column and NaNs for all another.

Comment: I would like to have 2 dates in each row of each df (df1, df2, df3) instead of just one which your code gives me.

Comment: @adrCoder - Not sure if understand, is possible add excpected output from your sample data?